# Why do nodejs function arguments behave differently when called explicitly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

I'm refactoring my nodejs app and am trying to make code look cleaner, then I encountered this problem when calling a function directly.

this works:

```
router.route('/').get(({ query }, res, next) => {
ItemsLogic.getItems(query)
  .then((items) => res.json(items))
  .catch(next)
```

})

but this throws error:

```
router.route('/').get(({ query }, res, next) => {
ItemsLogic.getItems(query)
  .then(res.json)
  .catch(next)
```

})

the error is : "Cannot read property 'app' of undefined". Its inside the `json()` function of express response and has to do with the `this` object in that method, which for some reason is undefined.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia — You can't pass "statements" (unless you put them in strings to be `eval`ed). The value of `res.json` is a function.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, you are right. Didn't not realized that `res.json` is a function. I guess that's what happens when you don't go through the code properly. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: to make this work, just pass : .then(res.json.bind(res))

Comment: @binariedMe would you put exactly that as an answer. That was actually what worked for me

Comment: @binariedMe And what would you think is more elegant?
(items) => res.json(items)
or
res.json.bind(res)

Comment: @DiegoManjarrés This question is already marked as duplicate so I can't put an answer. My opinion about elegant code would still be first one. 
Reason is that you should never propagate "req, res, next" variables to a different place. It should be used and visible within the route or subroute block. This helps readability of routes.

Comment: @DiegoManjarrés you may want to put a different question so that at least information in my last comment can be put forward if you will.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think the question that this one is marked as a duplicate of, is much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` inside a function depends on how it is called.

Given `res.json();`: `this` is `res`.

Given `var foo = res.json; foo();`: `this` is **not** `res`.

The `json` function cares about the value of `this`. By passing `res.json` you are taking the value of `json` (the function) and disconnecting it from `res` just like the second example above.